# Joining values indexed by date and time with irregular measurements

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, join, merge

I have two dataframes, both with a timestamp and some measurement; let's say measurement *X* and *Y*. I'd like to join these on their date/time index to compare the measurements but their timestampss are not exactly the same. Furthermore, the *X* measurement is taken more often than *Y*, so when joining, the *Y* value should only be appended to the row where the timestamp of *X* is closest and the other rows of *X* may be discarded.

These *X* and *Y* dataframes would look something like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=13, second=13), 4], 
                  [datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=15, second=24), 3],
                  [datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=18, second=36), 2],
                  [datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=21, second=56), 1]], columns=['time', 'x'])
```

```
y = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=13, second=59), 14], 
                  [datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=19, second=10), 13]], columns=['time', 'y'])
```

And the joined outcome based on these examples is supposed to look something like this:

```
joined = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=13, second=13), 
                        datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=13, second=59), 
                        4, 14], 
                       [datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=18, second=36), 
                        datetime(year=2022, month=9, day=6, hour=13, minute=19, second=10), 
                        2, 13]], 
                      columns=['time_x', 'time_y', 'x', 'y'])
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) after renaming the columns:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(y.rename(columns={'time': 'time_y'}),
                    x.rename(columns={'time': 'time_x'}),
                    left_on='time_y', right_on='time_x',
                    direction='nearest' # or leave the default backward depending on your use case
                   )
```

output:

```
               time_y   y              time_x  x
0 2022-09-06 13:13:59  14 2022-09-06 13:13:13  4
1 2022-09-06 13:19:10  13 2022-09-06 13:18:36  2
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have a dataset with multiple duplicate rows and the one where the timestamps are closest is somewhere in the middle of these rows? This would then keep the first row and delete all duplicates coming after it. Sorry, my example was not fully clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='nearest'`, then remove repeated rows:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(x.rename(columns={'time': 'time_x'}), 
                   y.rename(columns={'time':'time_y'}), 
                   left_on='time_x', right_on='time_y', direction='nearest')


df = df.drop_duplicates(['time_y','y'])[['time_x','time_y','x','y']]
print (df)
               time_x              time_y  x   y
0 2022-09-06 13:13:13 2022-09-06 13:13:59  4  14
2 2022-09-06 13:18:36 2022-09-06 13:19:10  2  13
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have a dataset with multiple duplicate rows and the one where the timestamps are closest is somewhere in the middle of these rows? This would then keep the first row and delete all duplicates coming after it. Sorry, my example was not fully clear.

Comment: @BasR - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: @BasR - Best is create new data sample in question for explain issue

Comment: Here, drop_duplicates() drops all rows and keeps the first encountered. But what if the second row is the one I'd like to keep because the difference in time between time_x and time_y is smaller here than the first row?

Comment: @BasR - What means `I'd like to keep because the difference in time between time_x and time_y is smaller` ? Is possible add data sample?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to solve the problem myself by calculating the difference between the times, sorting the dataframe and taking duplicates then. Thank you for the help!